# Solve: Changing parameters breaks the solution

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code:

```
n0 = 9.54472*10^(-5)
n1 = 3.72396*10^(-4)
n2 = 7.431*10^(-4)
n3 = 1.4862*1^(-3)
P0 = 2.53413*10^(5)

k0 = Exp[(Log[n1] Log[P0] - Log[n0] Log[P1]) / (Log[n1 / n0])]
gam0 = (Log[P0 / P1]) / (Log[n0 / n1])

Solve[k0 gam0 n1^(gam0 - 1) == 1, P1]
```

*Mathematica* is able to solve the equation for small values of `P0`, but not for the larger values that I need to `Solve` it for (such as the one in my example above).

What can I do to get this to work and to `Solve` this equation? I tried replacing `Solve` with `Reduce`, but this did not help.

Comment: Care to not be so condescending when talking to strangers ?

Comment: okarin, that's uncalled for. @Sektor helped you along by making your question more conforming to the style generally accepted here on MMA.SE. Your question will probably attract more attention now: for instance, you received an answer since Sektor's edit.

Comment: What @Sektor did is standard in this site. You shouldn't  care about someone else trying to improve the readability of your questions unless he spoiled something, which I believe isn't the case.

Comment: @Sektor I apologize for my comment (now deleted). I am under a lot of stress at work and not myself, but that is no excuse. It was rude and completely uncalled for. I hope I didn't offend you too much, and I appreciate your help in making my post more easily understood.

Comment: Marco, Oscar -- thank you for standing up for me :D @okarin No worries, that's why it's a community. Damn, been gone for 5 minutes and inbox went crazy :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation can be solved exactly by rationalizing the coefficients first

```
r = Rationalize;
n0 = r@9.54472*10^(-5);
n1 = r@3.72396*10^(-4);
n2 = r@7.431*10^(-4);
n3 = r@1.4862*1^(-3);
k0 = Exp[(Log[n1]*Log[P0] - Log[n0]*Log[P1])/(Log[n1/n0])];
gam0 = (Log[P0/P1])/(Log[n0/n1]);
s0 = First@Solve[k0*gam0*n1^(gam0 - 1) - 1 == 0, P1, Reals];
s[p_] := P1 /. s0 /. P0 -> p

LogLogPlot[{s[p0], p0}, {p0, 10^-9, 10^8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So for `P0 >> 0.1` you may approximate `P1` with `P0`